# How to get specific text from a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a string with the value "this-is-the-whole-string-value-33297af405e6". I want to extract the last number part from this string. The result I'm looking for is only "33297af405e6". How can I get this value?

Comment: benchmarked different solutions, and the winner is obvious, you could check my answer for the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `-`, and get the last part by calling [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) on the array:

```js
const input = "this-is-the-whole-string-value-33297af405e6";

const output = input.split('-').pop();

console.log(output); // 33297af405e6
```

Comment: `input.split('-').at(-1)` is more performant, modern and pure approach

Answer (score 4):

For the best performance nothing is faster than searching a string. It could be critical if you process a big JSON data. It's more than 3x faster than splitting the string:

```js
const str = 'this-is-the-whole-string-value-33297af405e6';
const found = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);

console.log(found);
```

And benchmarking different solutions:

```
` Chrome/120
----------------------------------------------------------------
lastIndexOf    1.00x  |  x10000000   142   143   143   149   152
split + at     1.14x  |  x10000000   162   167   167   167   171
split + pop    1.42x  |  x10000000   201   204   204   205   214
regex         12.01x  |  x10000000  1706  1735  1736  1755  1764
----------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script>

const str = "this-is-the-whole-string-value-33297af405e6";

// @benchmark split + pop

str.split('-').pop();

// @benchmark split + at

str.split('-').at(-1);

// @benchmark regex

str.match(/[^-]+$/)[0]

// @benchmark lastIndexOf

str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could also have used the split function. It is simpler and a better option.

Comment: @Swapnil Prakash It is only a better option, when your string has always a predefined structure. Regular expressions are much more versatile and powerful, but you must understand the somewhat cryptic expressions.  In this specific case it might be true, but in the general case it might not.